# Regex for mobile number with maximum number of 10

Tags: ios

Here's what I've tried so far. Is there something wrong with my Regex?

```
^(?:|0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?.{10}$
```

What i did was values must be numbers only and with a maximum number of 10. I have no idea what my code doesn't catch when I input more than 10 numbers.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What kinds of strings are you wanting to match?

Comment: use this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378736/regex-for-mobile-number-validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use following REGEX

`/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/`

For more information use following links:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want only numeric values from 1 to maximum 10 so this is the REGEX for that:

```
[0-9]{1,10}
```

If this is not what you need then let us know a little bit more.
You can use https://www.regex101.com to test your REGEX

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex, it also supports country code and spacing: `/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have a maximum of 10 numbers only?
The below regex works for 8-10 digits in the number

```
if ($phone =~ /^[0-9]{8,10}$/) {
    print "this is a valid phone number\n";
} else {
    print "not a valid phone number \n";
}
```