# How can i check that entered number is valid or not android?

Tags: android, numbers

I want to validate or identifying that the entered number is valid or not? For ex. i enter the number +91xxxxxxxxxx . Now i want to check that this number is real number or not? I don't want to use SMS gateway or calling system to identify the number.Like whatsapp.Whatsapp can identifying that the entered number is correct or not as per the country.

Comment: Then please ask all the n/w providers for an api.

Comment: You know any api for performing this action?

Answer (score 4):

May be a Regex can help you you can create your own regex according to your need have a look at below link

[Regex for Mobile Number Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378736/regex-for-mobile-number-validation)

and for explanation of your Regex just copy your regex and paste it in below link and it will explain it to you

http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: OP is asking if he can check if the entered number is a real number in use. Regex is not the solution. In fact there isn't any solution unless he wants to use SMS or Call gateway for verification.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Real Number means that if the number entered have correct syntax or not. If he is asking for that then it is not possible. and i think you misunderstood his question in last line he said i want to do the same as whats app so what whatsapp is doing is checking the syntax they do not call the Sim company to verify the number that if it is real or not.Thanks.

Comment: No i check that if i enter the wrong number which is not exist.then whatsapp can give the message that entered number is not exists.So i want to know how can they do this thing?

Comment: @ParinParikh Well You are right I forgot that thing. Whats app is using service for that and what i think they will have contacted Sim companies and have an agreement.