# Regex to validate all phone numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to build a regex to validate all types of phone numbers which `includes + ( ) . -`

Thanks to Google and stack overflow and i got a regex

```
/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/g
```

to validate all phone numbers.

But while validating `+(123 456-7890` the above regex not works as expected.
So I modified the above regex as

```
/^\+?([(]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{1}|[0-9]{1,3})([-\s0-9]*|[.\s0-9]*)\d+$/
```

and it works fine.

Now I need to restrict the user from entering consecutive `-` and dots`(.)`

So I manually validating that

```
if(HomePhone.indexOf("..") > -1 && HomePhone.indexOf("--") > -1) 
return false;
```

Could anyone help me to solve the above issue using a single regex by improving it..?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The way you are restricting the user not to give more than 3 consecutive digits, you can do that for the hyphens and dots, right? Think about it.

Comment: i have't give you down vote. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378736/regex-for-mobile-number-validation

Comment: @WasiAhmad the user can have space, periods and hypens but not consecutive. He can enter consecutive numbers

Comment: @NitinKumar  thanks for the link. let me see and try that out

Comment: @ManikandanSekar i can understand, the location of the space, periods and hyphens are also fixed. You just need to make sure user is restricted to put more than one hyphens or dots consecutively which is same what you have done for digits.

Comment: (123) 456-7890
+(123) 456-7890
+(123)-456-7890
+(123) - 456-7890
+(123) - 456-78-90
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
1234567890
+31636363634
075-63546725 

I need to write a regex to allow all the above cases and restrict the user from entering double (-) and (.)

Also if it contains open brackets, must have a close bracket

Comment: @ManikandanSekar i have added answer, you can check if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following regular expression will satisfy all your requirements.

Regex: `^\+?(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})(-. )?[0-9]{3}(-. )?[0-9]{4}$`

This regex should accept the following:

```
(123) 456-7890 
+(123) 456-7890 
+(123)-456-7890 
123-456-7890 
123.456.7890 
1234567890 
+3163636363 
075-6354672
```

You can modify this expression to adapt to your requirements, if required.

Answer (score 0):

use to match `..` and `--`  use regex `/(\.\.+|\--+)/g`

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/zIUhN6/2)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. as I mentioned in the post I need to validate multiple fields using the same regex so I removed the g flag.
I will try this