# django mobile number regular expression

Tags: django, mobile

I have seen many of the phone example as well as third party package for thie mobile number field. but what i want is this:

+country_code , or space (these 3 are optional) phone_number(min range number= 8, max is 13)
EG: +65, 98654578

based on one of the example and it work but not to what i wanted. 
: [What's the best way to store Phone number in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models)

```
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True) # validators should be a list
```

The one i made is this :

```
mobile_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{1-3}?\,?\s?\d{8-15}$', message="Phone number must not consist of space and requires country code. eg : +6591258565")
```

But it doesnt work. Did i do something wrong? please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Mobile Number Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378736/regex-for-mobile-number-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a dash instead of a comma, and given your instruction you also want to capture + and country code together, this regex works for me:

`^(\+\d{1,3})?,?\s?\d{8,13}`

Answer (score 0):

**All formats of mobile number validating expression in Python** 
`r'^\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}$'`